# can 'scrollIntoVeiw' be used for options in a select input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

when I click the select arrow and the menu appears, I want the menu to scroll down so the selected option is at the top of the menu (if there is enough scroll available). I have been trying this code:

```
$('#monthYear').click(function(){

  op = $('#monthYear option:selected');

  id = $(op).attr('id')
  el = document.getElementById(id);
  el.scrollIntoView();

});
```

but id doesn't do anything. Please check out this [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/do8tn3c5/18/) and let me know if you have any ideas. Thank you

Comment: Modern browsers should automatically scroll the dropdown to a  point where the selected option is visible.

Comment: it is visible, but I want it to be at the top of the menu (if scrolling permits)

Answer (score 0):

You can prepend the selected option so that it is on the top.

```
    $('#monthYear').click(function(){

    op = $('#monthYear option:selected');

    id = $(op).attr('id');
    console.log(id);
    el = document.getElementById(id);
    console.log(el);
    $("#monthYear").prepend(el);
   // el.scrollIntoView(true);

  });
```